# Calling NSDictionary with NSArray KeyValue issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array that loaded with data from other method. The data type is like that in the debug for `KEYS` as in the code.

`<__NSArrayI 0x9e82fc0>(
{
    "choice_name" = "Data0";
},
{
    "choice_name" = "Data1";
},
{
    "choice_name" = "Data2";
},`

Then I have called it twice in different method as I commented below and I get the value of the arrray: `array0` or `array1` nil. Where would be my problem?

```
- (void)requestPosistion:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request{

NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *result = [jsonString JSONValue];
[jsonString release];

if (![SettingVO isValidResponce:result]) return;

CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:[result objectForKey:@"Response"] options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

NSArray *nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/root" error:nil];

NSLog(@"choiceList is %@", nodes);

if([[[[nodes objectAtIndex:0] attributeForName:@"success"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"true"])
{

    NSArray *nodes3 = NULL;

    nodes3 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/root/cl_choicelist/cl_choice" error:nil];

    NSLog(@"node3%@", nodes3);

    res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CXMLElement *node in nodes3) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
            [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }

        [item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"choice_name"] stringValue] forKey:@"choice_name"];

        NSLog(@"item %@", item);
        [res addObject:item];
        [item release];
    }

    NSLog(@"res %@", res);
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:res forKeys:res];

    //NSArray *keys = [plistDict allKeys];

    //NSArray *array0 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[plistDict valueForKey:@"choice_name"]]; //array0 = nil.
    NSArray *array1 = [plistDict objectForKey:@"choice_name"]; //array1 = nil.
```

Comment: Put some more code, its very difficult to understand an issue with this.

Comment: What is "res" variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code looks like that:

```
 [[res objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"choice_name"] //returns Data0
 [[res objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"choice_name"] //returns Data1
```

Most probably you want to use "indexPath" at objectAtIndex:

```
 [[res objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"choice_name"]
```

Comment: I am getting this issue: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 164473424 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'  `NSArray *keys = [[res objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"choice_name"];`

Comment: Sry try [indexPath row]

Answer (score 0):

```
<__NSArrayI 0x9e82fc0>( { "choice_name" = "Data0"; }, { "choice_name" = "Data1"; }, { "choice_name" = "Data2"; },
```

This is an array. Inside the array you have object of `NSDictionary` with key "choice_name".

So in order to retrieve you need to iterate through the array to get all the kvp.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with:

```
NSString *str = [plistDict valueForKey:@"choice_name"];
```

You have string for that key nor array.
Is always good to make sure your plistDict is not nil.

Comment: I thing your array can be wrong. You probably want to pass NSString, is this right? I believe your array should looks like:{ "choice_name" = @"Data0" }, { "choice_name" = @"Data1" },...

Answer (score 0):

In NSDictionary you can have onelly one pair with key `@choice_name`. Even if you "put" more then one in NSDictionary, all other will just override previous value.

so valueForKey can return onelly one object and not the whole array, because there is onelly one key  `@choice_name`.

Comment: I can't write in @"choice_name" in forKeys.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that